# In Django i can't display a form in index, from another page. I only see the button, but i don't see the textboxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I would like to view the registration form directly on the index`.html` page (home page). In index.html, i would like to display `register.html`.

The registration form was created in registration/register.html. I call it in index.html using:

```
{% block content %}
{% include 'registration/register.html' %}
{%endblock%}
```

In the `urlpatterns` of `App1/views.py`, i use:

```
path("register_request", views.register_request, name='register_request')
```

The problem is that on the index.html i see the form button, but not its textboxes (username, email, password).

[image]

I can't understand where I'm wrong. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong and can you show me code how to fix it?

This is `App1`:

```
App1
.migrations
.static
.templates
..index.html
..registration
...register.html
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  .......
  .......
  {% block content %}
  {% include 'registration/register.html' %}
  {%endblock%}

</body>
</html>
```

**App1/templates/registration/register.html**

```
<!--Register--> 
<div class="container py-5">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ register_form.as_p }}                    
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="/login">login</a> instead.</p>
</div>
```

**App1/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your forms here.

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**App1/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
  path('', views.index, name='index'), 
  path("register_request", views.register_request, name='register_request'),
  ]
```

**App1/views.py**

```
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful." )
            return redirect("index.html")
        messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
    form = NewUserForm()
    return render (request=request, template_name="registration/register.html", context={"register_form":form})
    #NO: return render(request, "registration/register.html",{"register_form":form})
```

**MYSITE (PROJECT)**

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('App1.urls')),
```

**mysite/setting.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ....
        #NO: "DIRS" :  [ BASE_DIR  /  "templates" ],
        'DIRS': ["templates"], 
 [

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
```

In `models.py` i didn't write anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with how you're rendering the registration form. Since you want the form on the index page, there's no need for a separate view (`register_request`). Remove that view and handle the form processing directly in your `index` view. I've made some adjustments in the code snippet below.

```py
# In App1/views.py
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful.")
            return redirect("index")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
    else:
        form = NewUserForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'register_form': form})
```

Remove the `register_request` path in `App1/urls.py`:

```py
# In App1/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

These changes should display the registration form properly on your index page.

Comment: Remove def register_request (and write its code in def indec) and remove register_request path in App1/urls.py....is this just your advice or is it the ONLY way to achieve what I asked for?

Comment: There's no other view of rendering forms in django templates from another view, because it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check if expected form context name is correct